# How to use/reverse engineer Hash map keys

Tags: java, excel, vba, hashtable

I have never come across hash maps before so please be gentle!

I have a task whereby I have a hash map key (I think that’s what it is) and I want to reverse engineer it to get the data it was generated from.

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas about how to do this?

Can you do this in excel-vba or is it best to use Java? What functions should I use?

Do I need extra information in order to do what I want?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What "[hash] key" are you referring to and what is the "data"? It looks simply like auto-increment fields and a well-known (?) GUID column ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those aren't hash keys, they're GUIDs, "Globally Unique IDentifiers".  The bad news is that they are simply computer-generated unique strings - there was no "data they were generated from".

(If they were hash keys, the bad news would be that you can't recover the data they were generated from either - information is destroyed when hash keys are generated.)

Comment: That's the most nonrandom set of GUIDs I have seen.

Comment: @user2864740: All the more proof that they're not hash keys.  :-)